# Symfony2 Form Custom compound type

Tags: forms, symfony, custom-type

I'm trying to make a nullable integer, that is an integer which can also have a value set as null.

To do this, I was hoping to have an integer input with a check box to signify it is null (which could then have JavaScript hook up to disable/enable the integer input).

I see three ways of doing this:

1. Have a custom Type which has two fields.
2. Have a custom form widget which handles the two.
3. Some combination of one and two.

I'm not having any trouble with that, it's pretty straight forward.

What I can't seem to find any documentation about is how to get those two fields to funnel in to a single variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check in your controller. If the check box is `checked`, then the number is null. Why don't you just let the field empty when you don't want to fill it?

Comment: If I were to handle this in the controller I would have to handle this every time I wanted to use the type, not just once like in the Abstract type. I want to have an explicit checkbox for null (versus a blank field) so it is very explicit that you are setting it to null and not some default value (like 0, which is what the empty string would equate to). With what I'm working with, 0 and null mean two very different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can see is applying a [form transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to your form.

If the checkbox is checked you set null to your property, if it isn't you assign the value of your integer widget.

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634377/use-a-conditional-statement-when-creating-a-form) and apply this to your particular case.

*Side note: I wouldn't do this in the controller, it's not his job.*

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And agreed about the no-controller thing. I wanted something which I could set up purely in the type and then basically forget about what it is doing behind the scenes. =)