# Symfony2 Form validation dependency between form_types in one form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

In my symfony2 project I created a new **FormType** which is called "*ChoiceAndOrTextType*" which is a list of choices (checkboxes) but the user can also check the "others" option and write his answer into a *textfield*.

The code is like this one here in the answer of bschussek:
[Use a conditional statement when creating a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634377/use-a-conditional-statement-when-creating-a-form)

```
$builder
            ->add('choice', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['choices'] + array('Other' => 'Other'),
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('text', 'text', array(
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->addModelTransformer(new ValueToChoiceOrTextTransformer($options['choices']))
        ;
```

Now i want to validate this correctly, so when the user checks **"Others"** then the textfield needs to be filled out, if "Others" isn't checked it can be *blank*. (Kind of dependent validation).

**How do I do this?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two [validation constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html), for example in `validation.yml` yaml file

Comment: Yeah but this time the validation constraint depends on a choice made in the same form? How do I get this?